# Postgresql varchar to int

Tags: postgresql

I have a clothes size column in postgresql containing values such as (24, 25, "S", "M", "ONESIZE", "XL").

I need to extract from it only the integer values and convert the result to int.
I tried to_number in the format below, which works if the row contains a number, but does not work if it only contains letters.

```
select to_number('aq1', '99999D9') -> 1
select to_number('23', '99999D9') -> 23
select to_number('ONESIZE', '99999D9') -> error
```

I need a function that would work in a way that would allow me to join on the varchar column equal an int column.

```
select ???func("XL") -> null/0
select ???func(23) -> 23
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: If you need to join varchar on int (which is bad, try to avoid this), why don't you cast int to varchar and then join in the first place?

Comment: Good point, but i do need to later use those numbers, and I need a general solution from which we can all learn. A general solution via your approach would be to have a numbers table in varchar and int, and join via that.

Comment: data source is 3rd party, unavoidable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found a way although it does not look very neat. Perhaps someone knows a native function?

```
select to_number(concat('ONESIZE',0), '99999D9')/10 -> 0
select to_number(concat('23',0), '99999D9')/10 -> 23
```

as per cathulhu's suggestion, concating with leading 0 to avoid the division

```
select to_number(concat(0,'23'), '99999D9') -> 23
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
select COALESCE((select UNNEST(regexp_matches('XLds', '\d+')::integer[])), 0);
```

Notice that this regexp matches only first number in string.

Comment: matching the first number is sufficient for this case. Aspect(readability and maintainability) wise, it's ... not pretty. Any idea on speed vs the one in the other answer?

Comment: You can use your own idea as well, but why don't you concat with leading 0? Then you don't have to divide by 10: select to_number(concat(0, 'aq1'), '99999D9')